# How to retrieve data from xml node in MS Access?

Tags: xml, ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2000

I am developing a database application by using MS Access 2000, and it will be access some web services.  However, the data is returned in xml format. is there any way that I can import the xml data into a table in MS Access 2000?

Comment: http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-xml-vb6.asp - I think this has some decent info for you.  It's a start anyhow ...

Comment: Note that VBA is not VB6.  This question may be mis-tagged as VB6.

Answer (score 0):

### Note that VBA is not VB6. This question may be mis-tagged as VB6. – Bob Riemersma Jan 12 at 5:11

VBA = Ms Access .... VB6 isn't the language that you can use in it.